# Google App Engine - headers[] and headers.add_header() for cache control

Tags: python, google-app-engine, header, no-cache

What is the proper way to set cache control?

Sometimes I see the use of headers[]

```
self.response.headers["Pragma"]="no-cache"
self.response.headers["Cache-Control"]="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, pre-check=0, post-check=0"
self.response.headers["Expires"]="Thu, 01 Dec 1994 16:00:00"
```

Other times, I see headers.add_header()

```
self.response.headers.add_header("Pragma","no-cache")
self.response.headers.add_header("Cache-Control","no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, pre-check=0, post-check=0")
self.response.headers.add_header("Expires","Thu, 01 Dec 1994 16:00:00")
```

And even a mix of both headers[] and headers.add_header()

```
self.response.headers["Pragma"]="no-cache"
self.response.headers.add_header("Cache-Control","no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, pre-check=0, post-check=0")
self.response.headers.add_header("Expires","Thu, 01 Dec 1994 16:00:00")
```

Answer (score 10):

The difference is that using `headers[]` will overwrite previous values, while `add_header` won't.

From the wsgiref.headers [docs](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/module-wsgiref.headers.html) (referred to by the [GAE docs](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/webapp/responseclass.html#Response_headers)), "Setting a header deletes any existing values for that header, then adds a new value at the end of the wrapped header list."

Comment: So to set cache control, just use `headers[]` since these headers are single-valued (you don't want multiple `Pragma` headers to appear, for instance).